# Where can I find a full list of ready-to-graduate sites that don't have their own design yet?

Tags: support, beta-sites, graduating-sites

A number of sites have grown large enough and of high enough quality to warrant a full graduation, but due to bottleneck issues haven't gotten the shiny new coat of a fully fledged site yet. Where can I find a list of sites that fit in this category?

In particular, I'm curious whether the Music Stack Exchange site is on that list, but I would be interested in seeing a full list as well.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think a site is "graduated" until they have their own design.  So there is no graduated sites that don't have their own design. As you can see on the logo of [music.SE](https://music.stackexchange.com/) it says *beta*. Meaning it has not graduated yet.

Comment: @Roombatron5000: That's just nitpicking. Code Review, for example, got the official nod months ago, but it still says Beta because ... it doesn't have its own design yet. There is a real set of "sites that are waiting only on design to graduate", and it is presently non-empty.

Comment: This related question would be a start: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247739/162011.

Comment: @Nat But the sites still haven't actually graduated; they still have betaa privilege levels and beta mod-only migrations.

Comment: @cpast: Same thing: They aren't officially graduated (even though they're officially *ready* for it in all other ways and good to go), specifically because they don't have their own design yet, and for no other reason. So you're right, but it's irrelevant. I'll edit the title to fix that up.