# Is Beta Site Self-Evaluation Still Relevant?

Tags: discussion, review, beta-phase

Now that the graduation process for beta sites has been changed, will there be any more self-evaluation reviews?

It appears that they are no longer necessary.  A similar question:
[Where have the site self-evaluations gone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237472/where-have-the-site-self-evaluations-gone) was asked a year ago, before the graduation changes.  At that time self-evaluations were occurring less frequently.

They never seemed to attract much participation, and I haven't seen one for a while now.  Are they dead or just in limbo?  I don't think they'll be missed.

Comment: [Shutting down recurring community self-evaluations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261601/260841)...